# Acer Beni Maiko potting soil

Tags: compost, maple

I am new to gardening and have bought myself an Acer Beni Maiko tree. I  repotted it when I got home. I have been reading that they prefer slightly acidic soil. I have potted it in Westland's tree and shrub compost. This was a week ago.

Should I re-pot it again in a more acidic compost or should I leave it in the pot it is in (as I don't want to distress it too much having only recently repotted it the first time)
Any information would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the ph of that particular compost and it is 6.5, which is just about neutral, so your tree will be fine. Acer palmatum varieties don't like limey or alkaline soils rather than actually requiring an acidic soil, so no need to repot in ericaceous potting soil.